# Photo-frame-like widgets are not working on Lion/Mountain?

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, dashcode

I tried to write own widget for Mac OS Dashboard - kind of photo-frame displaying dropped image, but a bit more beautiful then others I found or used some time ago.

To have some resource/example I downloaded first... second... third widget in this type, but nothing works. I drag and drop image, but it doesn't load for me, nothing happens. I use 10.8.2 OS.
Could you check out it, or maybe you know why it's not working?

I tried with DeskPhoto ( http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/webcams/deskphoto.html ), 
Modern Moments ( http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/webcams/momentswidget_claudioprocida.html ) and Picture Frame ( http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/webcams/pictureframe.html )

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but I've found a way around it.

Open your image in your browser first then drag your image from there onto your widget. I found all the widgets work with the method.

Hope this works for you! =)

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same problem. Ended up using Decor which allows copy & paste of pictures. Maybe you could use that method?

http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/webcams/decor.html

Comment: If possible, you should include the solution in the answer just in case the link rots in the future.